# Using Refresh to skip expensive computations

Tags: dynamic

I have several variables in my `DynamicModule` and some parts of my computation depend only on subset of them. I am trying to use Refresh to "cache" values but can't make it work.

Example of the problem:

```
verySlowFunction[x_] := Module[{}, Print["SLOW"]; x * x];

DynamicModule[
 {a = 1, b = 1},
 Dynamic[
  Module[
   { x = Refresh[verySlowFunction[a], TrackedSymbols :> {a}] },
   Column[{
     Slider[Dynamic[a]],
     Slider[Dynamic[b]],
     {a, b , x + x + b} 
     }]]]]
```

I expect "SLOW" to be printed only when I drag "a" slider, but it is printed when I'm dragging "b" slider as well.

I know that Dynamic clones whole expression tree on its evaluation, that's why `x` is always different, but this one doesn't work as well:

```
Module[
 {x},
 DynamicModule[
  {a = 1, b = 1},
  Dynamic[
    x = Refresh[verySlowFunction[a], TrackedSymbols :> {a}] ;
   Column[{
     Slider[Dynamic[a]],
     Slider[Dynamic[b]],
     {a, b , x + x + b} 
     }]]]]
```

Comment: This is so useful: http://12000.org/my_notes/event_driven_GUI_with_Manipulate/event_driven_manipulate.htm

Comment: Do you know if this approach is actually used by anybody? I imagine there could be a library of helper functions to make it look simpler.

Comment: Besides the author, I am using it. I don't know who else, but it works beautifully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 1, x = 1}, 
 Column@{Slider@Dynamic[a, (a = #; x = verySlowFunction[a]) &], 
   Slider@Dynamic[b], Dynamic@{a, b, x + x + b}}]
```

The second argument in `Dynamic` is evaluated when the corresponding variable changes.

Or this one

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 1}, 
 Column@{Slider@Dynamic[a], Slider@Dynamic[b], Dynamic@{a, b}, 
   Dynamic[x = verySlowFunction[a]]}]
```

You can manually insert `Refresh` with `TrackedSymbols` in the last `Dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks, this will work. However in my actual case verySlowFunction depends on more than one argument, and there are several temporary calculations to perform. This would require me to duplicate re-evaluation into lots of controls, right?

Comment: @mikea There are more elegant approach if you have several arguments. See update.

Comment: The second version has some serious omission: it does not include calculations based on x. That's what causes me troubles.

Answer (score 1):

That's tricky question, I have to admit I do not have general solution but I usually do what is good for particular case. Here I'd use `DynamicWrapper`:

```
verySlowFunction[x_] := Module[{}, Print["SLOW"]; x*x];

DynamicModule[{a = 1, b = 1},
              DynamicWrapper[
                     Column@{
                             Slider@Dynamic[a],
                             Slider@Dynamic[b],
                             Dynamic@{a, b, x + x + b}},
                     x = verySlowFunction[a];]]
```

This is not the answer to the question how to use `Refresh` for your purposes but I think it is not bad approach :). I'm looking forward for more answers how one can deal with this.

About link provided by @Gustavo, imo there is to much acrobatics in there which is not necessary in case of `DynamicModule`. `DynamicModule != Manipulate` because the body of `DM` is not automatically updated when variables are.

I appreciate any comments if I'm mistaken somewhere.