# DynamicModule issues with Refresh, double evaluation, and CDF Player preview

Tags: dynamic, cdf-format, gui-construction

I am in the middle of making a CDF for a calculation of many random variables. I've gone with `DynamicModule` and have read the documentation plus these posts: [32294](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32294/using-refresh-to-skip-expensive-computations) and [30079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30079/what-is-the-right-way-to-construct-dynamicmodule). I've obviously missed a few things as it is not working as expected.

I have constructed the module as such (working snippet at the end of post):

```
DynamicModule[
 {dynamic variables},
 constant variables;
 Dynamic@Refresh[
  expensive calcs;
  plots and tables;
, TrackedSymbols->{update}]

Column[{controls for dynamic variables, plots, tables}],

Initialization :> (functions for calcs, plots, and controls),

UnsavedVariables :> {update},
SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

I am having 4 issues.

1. The controls created by the `makeControl` function (`variableRow` in the larger example) for the dynamic variables do not display on first execution but everything else does. That is, if you

   - delete the output cell,
   - quit and then start the kernel,
   - and execute the module

   then those controls show as the text of the commands that make them. Then executing the module a second time the controls show as the are supposed to.

   The plots and charts are linked to the update variable and refresh when the *Run Simulation* button is clicked on both the first evaluation and the second evaluation.
2. The `Dynamic@Refresh` keeps kicking out a `Null`. If I end it with a `;` then none of the plots and tables update when the *Run Simulation* button is pressed. This seems odd that making it not display output makes it not run the code inside.  How do I get rid of this `Null`? **Is this a bug?**
3. When previewed as *CDF Player* I get a ton of errors from the `FE'` context when I click the *Run Simulation* button. I have `SaveDefinitions -> True` on the module so am not certain why this is happening.
4. When the *CDF Player* is previewed moving the window it is in causes the simulation to repeatedly run. This only happens until the *Run Simulation* button is pressed. After it is pressed moving the window does not cause the simulation to run. It is an expensive simulation so this behaviour is very much not desired.

---

- First execution with previous output deleted and kernel quit and restart. Direct created controls (the popup and button) work and update the plot when as expected. The control created with `makeControl` is not available.
  [image: First execution with previous output deleted and kernel quit and restart.]
- Second execution immediately after first. The control created with `makeControl` is now available and updates the plot as expected with the other controls.
  [image: Second execution immediately after first.]
- `FE'` context errors from CDF Player preview.
  [image: <code>FE'</code> context errors from CDF Player preview]

---

**Added a smaller example of issue**

This has the same four problems described above.

```
DynamicModule[
 {numPoints = 100, interpolation = None, update = 1},

 plotColour = Pink;
 Dynamic@Refresh[
    data = RandomReal[{100, 1000}, numPoints];
    plot = plotPoints[data, plotColour, interpolation];
    ,
    TrackedSymbols -> {update}]

   Column[{
    Grid[{
      {"Control from function call", 
       makeControl[Dynamic@numPoints, {10, 1000, 10}, "Num Points"]},
      {"Direct created control", 
       PopupMenu[Dynamic@interpolation, Range[5], "Select ..."]}
      }],
    Button["Run Simulation", update = update + 1, ImageSize -> Large],
    Dynamic@plot
    }]
 ,
 Initialization :>
  (
   plotPoints[points_, colour_, interpOrder_] := 
    ListLinePlot[points, PlotStyle -> colour, 
     InterpolationOrder -> interpOrder, ImageSize -> 400];

   makeControl[variable_, range_, name_] :=
    Column[{variable,
      Slider[variable, range, Appearance -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Tiny]
      }];
   ),
 UnsavedVariables :> {update}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

---

**Orignal code snippet (too large and busy). Use simpler example above.**

It is a big module so I've taken a lot of things out while preserving my issue. The functions definitions have been reduced as well so please don't focus on the calculations.

```
DynamicModule[
 (* Parameters *)
 {numberOfRuns = 10000,
  investmentCaptial = 15000000,
  (* Many more dynamic parameters in this section *)
  μOverheadExpenses = 600000, σOverheadExpenses = 40000,
  μReturnOnInvest = 0.05, σSpliceLower = 
   0.03, σSpliceUpper = 0.02,
  update = 1},

 rtnPeriods = {50, 100, 250, 500, 1000};
 variableNames = {(* 
   more names for the omitted dynamic variables above *) 
   "OverheadExpenses", "ReturnOnInvestLogN", "ReturnOnInvestSpliceN"};
 (* A few other constant parameters in this section *)

 Dynamic@Refresh[
    (* Many distributions defined in this section to the dynamic parameters omitted above *)
    overheadExpensesDist = 
     NormalDistribution[μOverheadExpenses, σOverheadExpenses];
    returnOnInvestLogNDist = 
     LogNormalDistribution[1 + μReturnOnInvest, 
      Sqrt[σSpliceLower^2 + σSpliceUpper^2]];
    returnOnInvestSpliceNDist = 
     SplicedDistribution[{σSpliceLower/σSpliceUpper, 
       1}, {-∞, μReturnOnInvest, ∞}, { 
       NormalDistribution[μReturnOnInvest, σSpliceLower], 
       NormalDistribution[μReturnOnInvest, σSpliceUpper]}];

    (* Single step simulation *)

    sampleRuns = 
     Transpose[
      RandomVariate[#, numberOfRuns] & /@ {(* 
        More distributions here o the dynamic parameters omitted above *)
        overheadExpensesDist, returnOnInvestLogNDist, 
        returnOnInvestSpliceNDist}];

    runsAssoc = AssociationThread[variableNames, #] & /@ sampleRuns;

    (* Calculations begin *)
    {netIncomeInvestLogN, netIncomeInvestSpliceN} = 
     Transpose[(Function[{rtnOnInvest}, 
           netIncome[(* 
            More dynamic parameter names here *)#OverheadExpenses,

            Switch[rtnOnInvest, "ReturnOnInvestLogN", 
             Log[#[rtnOnInvest]] - 1, 
             "ReturnOnInvestSpliceN", #[rtnOnInvest]],
            investmentCaptial]] /@ {"ReturnOnInvestLogN", 
           "ReturnOnInvestSpliceN"}) & /@ runsAssoc];

    {netIncomeDistPlotLogN, 
      netIncomeDistPlotSpliceN} = {distributionPlot[
       netIncomeInvestLogN, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        "Investment Return \[Distributed] " <> 
         ToString@Head[returnOnInvestLogNDist], ImageSize -> 400], 
      distributionPlot[netIncomeInvestSpliceN, 
       PlotLabel -> 
        "Investment Return \[Distributed] " <> 
         ToString@Head[returnOnInvestSpliceNDist], ImageSize -> 400]};

    {netIncomeInvestLogNHdt, netIncomeInvestSpliceNHdt} = 
     DistributionFitTest[#, NormalDistribution[x, y], 
        "HypothesisTestData"] & /@ {netIncomeInvestLogN, 
       netIncomeInvestSpliceN};

    {netIncomeInvestLogNReturnPeriod, 
      netIncomeInvestSpliceNReturnPeriod} = 
     returnPeriodTables[{netIncomeInvestLogNHdt, 
       netIncomeInvestSpliceNHdt}, "Net Income"];

    (* More calcuations, tables, and plots on simulation *)
    ,
    TrackedSymbols -> {update}
    ]

  Column[{
    Grid[{
      {, "Distribution", "Mean", "Std. Deviation"},
      (* More variable rows here *)
      Evaluate@
       variableRow["Overhead Expense", "Normal", 
        Dynamic@μOverheadExpenses, {500000, 4000000, 25000}, 
        Dynamic@σOverheadExpenses, {30000, 100000, 5000}],

      {Item["Return On Investment", Alignment -> Center], "Log Normal",
       Item[
        Column[{Dynamic@μReturnOnInvest,

          Slider[Dynamic@μReturnOnInvest, {.01, .08, .005}, 
           Appearance -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Tiny]}, 
         Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
        Alignment -> Center],
       Item[
        Dynamic@Sqrt[σSpliceLower^2 + σSpliceUpper^2], 
        Alignment -> {Center, Bottom}]},
      {SpanFromAbove, "Splice Normal", SpanFromAbove,
       Row[{
         Column[{Dynamic@σSpliceLower,

           Slider[Dynamic@σSpliceLower, {.001, .1, .001}, 
            Appearance -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Tiny]}, 
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
         Column[{Dynamic@σSpliceUpper,

           Slider[Dynamic@σSpliceUpper, {.001, .1, .001}, 
            Appearance -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Tiny]}, 
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
         }, Spacer[2]]},

      {, "Number of Runs", 
       PopupMenu[Dynamic[numberOfRuns], Range[25000, 100000, 25000], 
        "Select ..."]}


      }],
    Button["Run Simulation", update = update + 1, ImageSize -> Large],


    Dynamic@netIncomeDistPlotLogN,
    Dynamic@netIncomeInvestLogNReturnPeriod
    }, Dividers -> {None, {-3 -> True}}]

 ,
 (* Initialise functions *)
 Initialization :>
  (
   netIncome[(* parameters removed for example *)overheadExpenses_, 
     returnOnInvestment_, investmentCapital_] :=
    returnOnInvestment*investmentCapital - overheadExpenses;

   distributionPlot[data_List, 
     opts : OptionsPattern[{Histogram, SmoothHistogram}]] :=
    With[{μ = Mean@data, σ = StandardDeviation@data},
     Show[
      Histogram[data, 30, "PDF", 
       Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Histogram]], 
       Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}}],
      SmoothHistogram[data, 
       Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[SmoothHistogram]]]
      ]];

   returnPeriodTables[hypoTestData_List, valueHeading_String] := 
    TableForm[
       Transpose@{Function[{rp}, 
           AccountingForm[InverseCDF[#["FittedDistribution"], 1/rp](*,
            DigitBlock\[Rule]{3,2}*)]] /@ rtnPeriods, rtnPeriods}, 
       TableHeadings -> {None, {valueHeading, "Return Period"}}] & /@ 
     hypoTestData;

   variableRow[name_String, 
     distributionName_String, μVariable_, μVariableRange_, σVariable_, σVariableRange_] :=
    {name, distributionName,
     Column[{μVariable,
       Slider[μVariable, μVariableRange, Appearance -> Tiny, 
        ImageSize -> Tiny]}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}],
     Column[{σVariable,
       Slider[σVariable, σVariableRange, 
        Appearance -> Tiny, ImageSize -> Tiny]}, 
      Alignment -> {Center, Center}]};
   ),
 UnsavedVariables :> {update},
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

Comment: @Kuba I thought that was a minimal example. :( I've taken a ton out to get it down to that. I wanted to preserve the function calls and things in case there was something wrong with my methods.

Comment: @Kuba I'll put something shorter up after I commute in to work.

Comment: I agree with @Kuba that this isn't a minimal example, removing the controllers (setting defaults in the variables of the `DynamicModule`) and reducing the visualisation to just the Histogram would of made this easier to inspect..

Comment: @Kuba Smaller example added.

Comment: @Edmund Thanks but are you multiplicating Dynamic with Column or purpose or is this a typo?

Comment: @Kuba That is because of issue number 2. If I end `Dynamic@Refresh` with a semicolon then the update button doesn't update. (version 10.1)  It is very odd.

Comment: @Edmund it is not odd. If you have a semi colon then the code is not displayed and dynamic only updates pixels that are displayed. Instead of multiplying a Dynamic by Column bring it into the Column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**
I've updated my answer entirely since the updated question

**First Issue**

As detailed in the documentation for `Initialization`, this expression is not evaluated until after the content of the `DynamicModule` has been evaluated and not until "the construct is first displayed". This requires that any `Initialization` variable must be wrapped in `Dynamic` to be displayed in the `DynamicModule` output. As a minimal example, see here:

```
DynamicModule[{localV},
 Grid[{{Slider[Dynamic@localV], 
    function[Dynamic[localV], "Hello World"], globalV}}],
 Initialization :> (function[a_, b_] := {b, a}; globalV = 33)]
```

[image]

Wrapping the entirety of the `Grid` in `Dynamic` fixes that:

```
DynamicModule[{localV},
 Dynamic@Grid[{{Slider[Dynamic@localV], 
     function[Dynamic[localV], "Hello World"], globalV}}],
 Initialization :> (function[a_, b_] := {b, a}; globalV = 33)]
```

Wrapping `Dynamic` around `makeControl[Dynamic@numPoints...]` in your code will fix this issue.

**Second Issue**

I cannot explain why your example actually works in the absence of the `CompoundExpression` (`;`), but I can explain how to use `Refesh` in the way you would like.

`Refresh` only affects the `Dynamic` it is local to, not the entire `DynamicModule` interface. See the following example below. Note the necessity to include `x;y` for `y` to be updated, as detailed in the excellent answer from @MichaelE2 here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21643/1952.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y}, Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[x]], Slider[Dynamic[y]],
   {"x", Dynamic[x]},
   {"unlimited y", Dynamic[y]},
   {"limited y", Dynamic@Refresh[x; y, TrackedSymbols :> {x}]}
   }]]
```

Your example can therefore be fixed by expanding the `Dynamic` owning your `Refresh` to the entire first argument of the `DynamicModule`

```
DynamicModule[
 {numPoints = 100, interpolation = None, update = 1},

 plotColour = Pink;
 Dynamic@Refresh[
    data = RandomReal[{100, 1000}, numPoints];
    plot = plotPoints[data, plotColour, interpolation];
    ,
    TrackedSymbols -> {update}]

   Column[{
    Grid[{
      {"Control from function call", 
       makeControl[Dynamic@numPoints, {10, 1000, 10}, "Num Points"]},
      {"Direct created control", 
       PopupMenu[Dynamic@interpolation, Range[5], "Select ..."]}
      }],
    Button["Run Simulation", update = update + 1, ImageSize -> Large],
    Dynamic@plot
    }]
 ,
 Initialization :>
  (initialisationstuff),
 UnsavedVariables :> {update}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

**Third Issue**

While you do have `SaveDefinitions->True` you do have `UnsavedVariables`, if this is removed your example will work perfectly on my machine.

**Fourth Issue**

Turns out that there is an issue with `PlotTheme` potentially making `Dynamic` visualisations sensitive to window movements, as identified by @SquareOne here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/75489/1952

Comment: I'm always interested in suggestions. What ideas do you have in mind? It's a good time for me to get them as I've not started to pretty it up yet.

Comment: This removes the `Null` but is a lot of code to move there and it is not a clean looking solution. Many calculations, plots, and tables are not included in the example.  I feel as if `Refresh` is the way to go because of this. If keeps the code in a separate area then the display and it is easier to manage it this way. Is there a way to wrap all of the calculations in to a variable and execute that in the button? I've tried `Inactivate` and `Activate` but that didnt' work out. Any ideas on the other issues?

Comment: @Edmund I owe you an update but w/o Mma at present. The question has been updated with more detail than initially, your question may be better answered by others reviewing your update. I will attempt to answer but may simply update in the vein of my original answer.

Comment: An amazing answer. Thank you so much for pointing out my mistakes. This is the first time I've tried a non-standard do-it-yourself interface. I'll be much better off with this information.